# Unable to copy() image from one folder to another

Tags: php

I am trying to copy an image from one folder to another. I feel that my paths are wrong, but I have tried so many path combinations that I am now unsure whether it is the problem.

I am trying to copy an image (if it exists) from the `user_photos` folder, into the `profile_pics` folder. Here are where they are located, as well as the script, known as, `change_dp.php`, which once called, will execute the `copy()`.

```
www > user_data > user_photos > photos_are_here
www > user_data > profile_pics > photos_are_here
www > inc > change_dp.php
```

Here is `change_dp.php`:

```
$all_pics = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_photos WHERE username = '$username'");
    $row_query = mysqli_fetch_assoc($all_pics);
            $get_photo_owner = $row_query['username'];
            $get_photo_id = $_GET['id'];

$get_pic_with_id = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM user_photos WHERE id = '$get_photo_id'");
    $row_query2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_pic_with_id);
            $img_url = $row_query2['img_url'];

    $file = $img_url;
    $arrPathInfo = pathinfo($file);
    $shortened_url = $arrPathInfo['basename'];

if (file_exists($file)) {
copy("../../" . $file, "../../profile_pics/" . $shortened_url); 
}

$pro_pic_change = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE users SET profile_pic='$shortened_url' WHERE username = '$username'") or die ($connect);
     header("Location: /photos/$get_photo_owner");
```

Just to illustrate the issue more:

- User uploaded photos (which are stored in user_photos) are stored in there full path in my database, for example, if Alice uploads a file called `alice.jpg`, it will be stored as `user_data/user_photos/alice.jpg`. This is why I have varible `$shortened_url` which will only get the base name of the file i.e. get the `alice.jpg` from `user_data/user_photos/alice.jpg`. I need the `$shortened_url` because column `profile_pics` in the database holds just the base name of the image, not the full path.
- With the `if statement`, I am trying to get the basename of the image, see if an image with the same name in my `user_photos` file exists, and if it does, copy it into the `profile_pics` folder and set the basename to `profile_pics` column via an UPDATE statement. The UPDATE statement works fine, the image name does change in the database, but the image just doesn't copy over, which corrupts the image since it cant find it in the `profile_pics` folder.

What I have tried:

```
copy($file, "../profile_pics/" . $shortened_url); 
copy("../../" . $file, "../../profile_pics/" . $shortened_url);
copy($file, "user_data/profile_pics/" . $shortened_url);
```

None which work.

**Edit**:

Here's what I want the code to do:

Lets assign values to `$file` for an example:

```
$file = user_data/user_photos/alice.jpg
```

1. See if an image with the name of $file exists in the `user_photos` folder.
2. If there is a file with the name of `alice.jpg` in the folder, then copy that image into the `profile_pics` folder.
3. That's it.

Comment: You should add some tests into your code to determine at what point the script is failing.  Perhaps an else on the file_exists code to display a message to yourself if it's simply not finding the file to begin with.

Comment: @LukePittman - Hmm, seems you're right. I have an else statement which echo's `don't exist` and with all the `copy()` paths above, they all echo the else statement - meaning none of the `copy()` can find the file. But how can I resolve this? I need it to see if the file exists and cannot think of other ways to check for its existence without `if (file_exists($file)`?

Comment: Can you show your updated code?

Comment: @LukePittman - Sure, not much has changed though, except the if statement: `if (file_exists($file)) {
   copy("../../" . $file, "../../profile_pics/" . $shortened_url);
  } else {
   echo "<hr/>dont exist";
  }`` .. Everything else remains the same, as depicted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `__DIR__` magic constant and then based on that you can go to upper levels in the directory hierarchy, by using `realpath()` function or even `dirname()` function. This way it will be less confusing and less error prone.

E.g.:

```
$upOneLevel = realpath(__DIR__."../");
$upTwoLevels = realpath(__DIR__."../../");
```

So to access your file you shoud use:

```
$fileRealPath = $upOneLevel."/".$file;
$fileRealDestination = $upOneLevel."user_data/profile_pics/".$shortened_url;
```

I also recommend to update the data in the DB only if the file exists and the copy command executes successfully:

```
if (file_exists($fileRealPath)) {
    if(copy($fileRealPath, $fileRealDestination)) {
        //TODO db logic here
    } else {
        //TODO error handling here        
    }
} else {
    //TODO error handling here
}
```

Comment: Ahh, the code needed slight tweaking, i.e. `$fileRealPath =$upTwoLevels."/".$file;` instead of `$upOneLevel`. But besides that, the code works! Thank you very much :).